# connection.sync({ force: false}) creates unwanted table

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am playing with a code I have found on 'Medium' and changed the name of the tables in my models, form:

```
const connection = require ('../connection');
const { Sequelize } = connection;

const User = connection.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: connection.Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    password: Sequelize.STRING

});

module.exports = User;
```

to:

```
const connection = require ('../connection');
const { Sequelize } = connection
const User = connection.define('Users', {
    id: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: connection.Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    password: Sequelize.STRING

});

module.exports = User;
```

I have also changed the name of the table in my database.

I have then decided to return to the original names.
Since then however, every time I run the entire code, my database shows 2 tables:

```
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_database |
+--------------------+
| user               |
| users              |
+--------------------+
```

Note that I have changed the table name from 'user' to 'Users' and not to 'users', but the table created is 'users'.

Nevertheless, I dropped the table 'users' but if I run the code, it is re-created.

I have looked everywhere and it doesn't seems to be any reference to a 'users' table or model. 
the only thing that prevented the table to be created is to remove the following line from the index.js:

```
connection.sync({force: false});
```

Why is this happening and how can I prevent the table to be created and even with the connection.sync still in place?

Comment: Could be useful to know that 'connection.sync' logs the following: Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` CHAR(36) BINARY , `name` VARCHAR(255), `password` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think this can help you :**

```
const Bar = sequelize.define('bar', { /* bla */ }, {
  // disable the modification of table names; By default, sequelize will automatically
  // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
  // if you don't want that, set the following
  freezeTableName: true,

  // define the table's name
  tableName: 'my_very_custom_table_name',
})
```

For more detail : **[DO READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration)**

Comment: Thank you Vivek for your answer!